# How can I allow packet forwarding via Windows Firewall?

Tags: windows, firewall

In the Linux I can use iptables for enable forwarding:

```
~ # iptables -I FORWARD -j ACCEPT
```

But how can I realize the same function in Windows?

Comment: What version of Windows? Routing capabilities are limited to Server editions AFAIK.

Comment: @stickybit win 2008

Comment: Don't post the same question multiple times. These two things can and should be posted as one question.

Comment: In Linux they are two different steps, not same .

Comment: They have the same purpose and are two steps necessary to achieve one goal.

Comment: ... not. The windows firewall is just a firewall, neither a router nor forwarder.